# System of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've tried to solve the following simple system:

$
\Bigg\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\dot{x}=y \\
\dot{y}=\frac{y^2}{x}
\end{array}
$

After some algebra (differentiating the first equation, then plugging in the square of $\dot{x}$, then differentiating the second expression, plugging in the expression for $\dot{x}$ from the first and for $x$ from $x=\frac{y^2}{\dot{y}}$. I got the following two equations for each variable that made me think something went wrong somewhere:

$
\Bigg\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\ddot{x} x -\dot{x}^2=0 \\
\ddot{y} y -\dot{y}^2=0 
\end{array}
$

I probably made some silly mistake, in such case pls don't solve it for me, just point in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Compute the derivative of $\dfrac{\dot{x}}x$.